# Want to open SharePoint online pages in ionic angular in-app browser, will it be okay?

Tags: ionic2, office365, office-ui-fabric

I need to open office 365 modern pages in ionic angular based mobile app.
I know i can just check it by doing. 
but still i would like to listen from you experts that whether it is a good idea to load a page (which may have react components on it) in ionic angular based app. 
Can it create any problem in future ?
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Waiting for a response please

Comment: Any one please?